# Browser wont show full screen when looking at it resposively

Tags: browser, responsive

Im working with media queries right now and when i press inspect element to look how the site works from other devices it does not show as full-screen. Only half of the image is showing, which is so frustrated.
To let you know what i mean, heres a picture
https://imgur.com/a/tBBXL

Ive been trying to change the resolution but that doesnt help. it just shows how big of a window i have.
Been trying to change the resolution of the media queries im using but thats not working either.
Im using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) and (min-width: 220px){}
```

But overall it does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it was the settings in the chrome browser that caused the problem.
It was working for IE and firefox.